# The estimate for $\sum_{0}^{\infty} e^{-kn^2}-e^{-k(n+1/2)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, analysis, theta-functions

I'm trying to give estimate on the following infinite summation:

$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (e^{-kn^2}-e^{-k(n+\frac{1}{2})^2})$,
and k is some fixed positive number.

The first term in the summation seems to be the $\psi$ function, but I dont know how to deal with the second term.

Thank you advance to anyone who could help.

Comment: Does the sum go over $k$ or $n$? I think the second one, but just to be sure.

Comment: You have a theta constant. $\,\theta_4(0,e^{-k/4})$. Consult Wikipedia [theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function).

Comment: This is just the difference between theta functions. If $k$ is of the form $\pi\sqrt {p} $ where $p$ is a positive integer then the expression in your question has a closed form in terms of $\pi$ and values of Gamma function at rational points. In particular $k=\pi$ gives the closed form $$\frac{\Gamma (1/4)}{2^{1/2}\pi^{3/4}}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{1/4}}\right)$$

Comment: It is not hard to show that $$\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2} 
        \leq \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-n^2/(2\sigma^2)} 
        \leq \sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2} + 1$$ (for any $\sigma>0$, so in your case $\sigma=1/\sqrt{2k}$), via the Poisson summation formula and a comparison series/integral (for the upper and lower bounds). Similarly for the shifted sum, I gather. You can have tighter estimates, if that is not enough, but they're less straightforward.